# How to detect 'Shift + Enter' in ReactJS onKeyPress event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard

How to detect 'Shift + Enter' in ReactJS onKeyPress event?

Is it possible ?

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/cyLqfcts/3/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  handleKeyPress(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
    $('#app').append("<br/>" + e.key);
  }
  render() {
    return ( < textarea defaultValue = {
        ""
      }
      onKeyPress = {
        this.handleKeyPress
      }
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your answer is detecting on 'Enter' not 'Shift+Enter'. This should help!
https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/c2hzt27g/3/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.shiftKey) {         
      $('#app').append("<br/> Detected Shift+Enter")
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea 
        defaultValue = {""}
        onKeyUp={this.handleKeyPress}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: hmm... isn't it the same thing ?

Comment: It's not. You won't see anything if you just press 'Enter'. You need to press 'Shift + Enter'

Comment: Edited the comment.. Pressed 'Enter' by mistake.

Comment: oh. that doesn't really matter. It's only to show that shiftKey can be detected. `e.shiftKey` and `e.nativeEvent.shiftKey` is the same thing. Anyway, thanks for you help. Will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: The jQuery append that you did, should have been done the React way.